# Copy PDF table into Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am a rookie in VBA and I have a task, which is writing codes using VBA to copy tables from PDF into Excel needs to be done.

I have searched on Google about this task, and the answers that I could get is that the requirement has to be Acrobat Professional. However, I am using Acrobat Reader.

Here is the concept flow that I have come out with.

1. Declare variables
2. Initialize Variables
3. Open PDF
4. Search "keywords"
5. Copy everything below the "keywords"
6. Activate Excel and go to the cells
7. Paste the table

However, I have met some obstacles in searching "keywords" and copy the table.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is highly non-trivial, and probably impossible without Acrobat Professional. Here is a starter link: http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=5907 -- Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: it is not possible with Adobe Reader especially if you want to programmatically run the text selection. You should use Acrobat Professional via its API or 3rd party ActiveX / VBA compatible tools designed for text search/extraction.

Comment: @Andre Thanks for your info. I found the link very helpful!

Comment: @EugeneM Okay. Thanks for your help.